# Help on reading switch datasheet

Tags: mosfet, current, switches, pcb-design

I am looking to buy a switch for 85Vdc and 16A.

https://www.alliedelec.com/m/d/dbd1a0ffce5b4bc03b21347df857ba1b.pdf

I was looking at this datasheet and it appears to be ok for 20A @ 125Vdc.
Can someone give me a second opinion?  I ask because usually there is an ac rating that is drastically different than the dc, but here it says they are the same and I want to confirm if this is correct.

Comment: It should be fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

Honestly, I am unsure why you need a second opinion. It says it right there. If you are unsure, contact the suppliers. But a datasheet would not explicitly write AC or DC if either one could not live up to the stated specs.